# CSS Animation on hover

Tags: css, animation

I need a little help with CSS animations. How can I make this http://jsfiddle.net/nmsdvid/TdnVs/ just with CSS. So, when I hover over the krab div a css animation will start and going to switch images (vws02.png than vws01.png than vws02.png) while I'm on hover.

Comment: you are doing it well (first image static, second image with animated gif), CSS can't start and stop nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The example of krab you have given is done with the css only. On image hover they have just changed the image form http://nmsdvid.com/images/vws01.png to http://nmsdvid.com/images/gif.gif. If you see the second image is already a .gif image(animated image).

Answer (score 1):

here you check

#krab {
        width:335px;
        height:345px;
        background-image:url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg);
    }

#krab:hover {
background-image:url(https://image.winudf.com/v2/image/Y29tLnp6d3BuZXcudGlnZXIzRF9zY3JlZW5zaG90c18wX2NhZWNhNzYz/screen-0.jpg?h=355&fakeurl=1&type=.jpg);
    }

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TdnVs/4/